# Why does Coinbase block SatoshiDice transactions?

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com, satoshidice

I noticed that Coinbase won't allow you to make transactions to [SatoshiDice](http://www.satoshidice.com/). Is this due to SatoshiDice being blocked in the US due to online gambling regulations, or are there additional reasons for this restriction?

What other transactions have Coinbase known to have blocked, if any?

Comment: Unless coinbase decides to make a statement about this, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Is Coinbase a hosted (shared) E-Wallet, or instead is it a hybrid E-Wallet in which all transaction addresses are associated with my account and my account only?

Answer (score 2):

I think its because you are not supposed to play blockchain spam type dice games with online wallets. Since when you win, the winnings goto whatever address it was sent from. Therefore, it may not end up back in your wallet.

All the games are like this, most even have a list of "compatible wallets". I think the only online one that will work is the one ar blockchain.info

another rule of thumb, if you don't have access to the private key, you shouldn't use the address to gamble with